# Vim in terminal is slow

Tags: linux, vim, terminal, gnome

I'm using vim in the terminal a log and I'm getting frustrated with its slow performance. I'm on Debian Jessie using Gnome.

If I open a file in vim do a block select and `I` to insert on multiple lines there is always a delay from when I press esc to when the change is inserted.

If I do the the same thing in gvim the change is imidiate.

I have tried adding

```
set ttyfast
set lazyredraw
```

In my ~/.vimrc but that does not make any noticeable difference.

```
$ vim --verion
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Nov 20 2015  15:31:14)
Included patches: 1-930
```

Comment: What terminal emulator are you using?

Comment: Do you have a mapping that starts with Escape? Check `:map <Esc>` and `:map! <Esc>` for any output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is completely normal.

In Vim, some special keys (like the cursor keys) are implemented as `<Esc>` followed by some other character. Therefore, Vim waits a bit after your press `<Esc>` to determine if you actually wanted `<Esc>` or if you wanted something else like `<Esc>A` (`<Up>`).

See `:help 'timeout'`, `:help 'timeoutlen'`, `:help 'ttimeout'`, and `:help 'ttimeoutlen'`.